# Data Organization in Custom 3D Mesh File Format

Tags: opengl, c++, opengl-es, 3d-meshes

After careful consideration to use middleware, I have decided on creating my own 3d file format format to export meshes from 3D authoring application (Softimage) into my game.

*I will need to export the following:*

- Vertices
- Indices
- Normals
- UVs
- Material Information
- Animation information (no clue, how to import it)
- Collision mesh
- Game Properties defined within 3D authoring tool (object intelligence, aggressivity, etc..)
- ..another assets..

Can I kindly ask for a hint, how to construct my custom file format. How to organize data within my files, please? Does anoybody have a good adivce on exporting animation information, especially when the mesh changes its geometry?

I would be thankful for advices that could point me into right direction. It would be nice to save some time instead of wasting it on incorrect approaches.

*I use Softimage as my 3D authoring tool. Target platform is OpenGL ES 2.0 running on mobile devices (iOS, Android). Programming language: C++.*

Comment: Personally it seems like you're going in the reverse order.  Figure out what your *engine* needs (and how it's organized), and then just put that data in a file format.

Comment: @Tetrad: Thanks for your comment. I have already created the core of my game, so it is basically up to me, how I decide to format the data. I will have to write file importer in my game as well.

Comment: What sort of animation are you doing? Keyframed mesh interpolation (one new mesh per animation frame), or keyframed skeletal animation (mesh with vertex weights, bones, etc.)?

Comment: What sort of collision meshes do you need? Actual meshes, or can you fake it with a cylinder, or what?

Comment: I don't mean to be mean--I'm just trying to figure out the bare minimum subset you need for what you are doing. I've done a (pretty fast) binary static mesh format, and some of these questions let us simplify your problem space. Also, you don't mind writing a tool to handle import to your format, do you? If you don't, that also significantly simplifies your issue--you can just use AssImp to digest whatever Softimage puts out, and convert to your own file format (would suggest this, in fact).

Comment: @ChrisE: Hi Chris, thanks for your attention. I will need both types of **animation** (interpolated meshes and keyframed skeletal animation). I wish to create a format, that will suit all my needs in the whole game. Regarding **collision meshes**, I will have to define my own real meshes. The objects are irregular, and at some points I will need precise collison detection. Where possible, i will use cubes, cylinders, spheres, of course.

Comment: @ChrisE: Yes, AssImp is good recommendation. However, I have already created my set of plug-ins within Softimage. I have analyzed AssImp, and because it does not support Softimage, I would need to export it into non-native format, which would be converted via AssImp. Besides that, I would need to keep collision mesh in separate files. For thsese and other reasons, I would like to write my own exporter, another plug-in within Softimage. I could simply add anytihing I need, plus a set of game properties/values defined within Softimage.

Comment: Ah, okay, that's cool. One thing to note is that, as AssImp supports groups in various formats, you could have a group named "_collision" or somesuch, and have your tool pick up on it. I haven't done Softimage plugins, so I don't know what properties they expose. Was just talking about what I know. I'll try to put together an answer for you sometime tonight.

Comment: @ChrisE: If you are so kind, it would be helpful. I am just thinking about some good way of representing data within my files. So far, the best approach I can think of is Wavefront .obj file format. But maybe, there is something better and more efficient. Maybe collada format., but it seem a bit complex and can be limiting (animations, collision meshes). Any advice will be helpful. Thanks in advance, Chris.

Comment: Oh, do you need a binary file format, or do you want text?

Comment: @ChrisE: At the beginning, I consider writing text format. This will bring me readability advantage, which is essential for debugging. Later, during optimization phase, plan to switch to binary format. When the text file format is defined and tweaked, it sould not be that difficult to modify it into binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, I haven't received any answer so far, to provide you with some solution, let me tell you how I solved it.

In the beginning, I use text file format. It is easier to read and debug my application. The text format is based on [WaveFront .obj](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) file architecture, and I simply add the tags, as needed.

When I have complete text file format, I will create binary format, that will reflect the data stored directly in my application, so I will minimize the need for parsing, to make the format as fast as possible.

Comment: Am I missing something, but couldn't you just save to a binary format and just adjust your loading algorithm (thus much faster load/read times)?

Comment: @The Communist Duck It's usually much better to save in a interchange format that can be reopened again in your DCC app, and then compile it to a app specific format. This will reduce a lot of engine/game code and you will have a lot foster loading since you don't have to translate data or change layout.

Comment: @The Communist Duck: The reasons that led me toward text file format firstly were my skills level. I needed to see what data gets exported from 3D authoring application. When sloving bugs, I needed to quickly edit and change data in the file, to search for the causes of problems. If I go with binary file format from beginning, I thought, things would be too messy for me to progress quickly.